# Is it comfirmed that Alzheimer's is a diabetes of the brain?

Tags: brain, insulin

I read in [this New Scientist report](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg22029453-400-are-alzheimers-and-diabetes-the-same-disease/), that the mental decline during diabetes *may* be an early stage of Alzheimer's.  The hypothesis was based on a study with 20 rats.

Has there been any follow up research? Is Alzheimer's such a slow disease that this is will be remain hypothetical for a while?  Are there any other links between diabetes and Alzheimer's that can point in either way?

Or has research even confirmed (or refuted) another weaker hypothesis true, namely, the mental decline during diabetes and Alzheimer's have a common cause?

Many times newspapers say this or that is being research and we will know one day whether this is true or false; but the same newspapers hardly ever do follow up reporting.  So this is why I am asking this here.

Comment: You need to pay more attention to the statements. It is nowhere written (at least in peer-reviewed journals) that diabetes **causes** AD. They only say (if they did) that diabetes is **a factor** Correlation and causation are different. Also, dependence may not mean strictly causation. These terms may seem to have subtle differences but they mean different things.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I guess I should have used the wording "... that diabetes and Alzheimer's might have a common cause".

Comment: Far from being confirmed, the notion that diabetes is a significant factor in Alzheimers is held by at most a tiny, tiny minority of researchers.  New Scientist is notorious for wild-eyed hyping of fringe speculation; this is an example.

Comment: Some researchers consider Alzheimer's type 3 diabetes. There are lots of papers on the mechanisms involved.